# How to get the server session with token in my next web app api backend?

Tags: typescript, next.js, postman, next-auth

I'm trying to configure my Next.js backend api to effectively handle POST requests from external sources (like Postman). The main objective is to extract session data on the backend, enabling me to make calls to tRPC methods and authenticate the token that comes with the request.

```
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)

  if (!session) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "You must be logged in." });
    return;
  }

  return res.json({
    message: 'Success',
  })
}
```

This is the NextAuth example of doing it, how do I need to setup my request in order to get the session back?